# Shell Script Isn't Deleting Empty Directories In Certain Situations

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script to organize files.  As of now, it doesn't support a ton of types, just enough to test it out.  The workflow is this:

1. Make folders for a type of items
2. Move all items with wildcards
3. Delete all empty folders

   Repeat this for other types of files.

As of now, the directory deleting part works if nothing was ever stored in it.  So, if I run the script and nothing was ever moved to a folder, it will be deleted during that first run.  However, if folders were made and items were moved to it, if I manually delete those items (making the folder empty) and run the script again, the directories aren't deleted.

Anyone have any ideas what is causing this?  I don't claim to know a ton about shell scripting and even got the syntax for checking for an empty directory here on SO.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add support for other files and formats
# Figure out how to move all rest of files to MISC without moving the script
# Figure out why folders are deleted, unless they have an item stored at some point
# Figure out how to copy files from existing folders out and make them empty
# so they can be sorted, and they will be deleted in the end

########################################## AUDIO ##########################################

# Make folders for audio
mkdir Audio
mkdir Audio/AIFF
mkdir Audio/FLAC
mkdir Audio/MP3
mkdir Audio/WAVE

# Move all audio files to audio folder
mv *.aiff Audio/AIFF
mv *.flac Audio/FLAC
mv *.mp3 Audio/MP3
mv *.wav Audio/WAVE

# Delete any empty folders related to audio folder - delete parent folder last
# Because it will only ever be empty at the end of deleting all other subfolders
if [ "$(ls Audio/AIFF 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Audio/AIFF
fi

if [ "$(ls Audio/FLAC 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Audio/FLAC
fi

if [ "$(ls Audio/MP3 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Audio/MP3
fi

if [ "$(ls Audio/WAVE 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Audio/WAVE
fi

if [ "$(ls Audio 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Audio
fi

########################################## DOCUMENTS ##########################################

# Make folders for documents
mkdir Documents
mkdir Documents/DOC
mkdir Documents/DOCX
mkdir Documents/HTML
mkdir Documents/RTF
mkdir Documents/TXT

# Move all docs to documents folder
mv *.doc Documents/DOC
mv *.docx Documents/DOCX
mv *.html Documents/HTML
mv *.rtf Documents/RTF
mv *.txt Documents/TXT

# Delete any empty folders related to documents folder - delete parent folder last
# Because it will only ever be empty at the end of deleting all other subfolders
if [ "$(ls Documents/DOC 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Documents/DOC
fi

if [ "$(ls Documents/DOCX 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Documents/DOCX
fi

if [ "$(ls Documents/HTML 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Documents/HTML
fi

if [ "$(ls Documents/RTF 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Documents/RTF
fi

if [ "$(ls Documents/TXT 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Documents/TXT
fi

if [ "$(ls Documents 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Documents
fi

########################################## IMAGES ##########################################

# Make folders for images
mkdir Images
mkdir Images/GIF
mkdir Images/JPEG
mkdir Images/JPG
mkdir Images/PNG

# Move all Images to folder - Split up files into specific file extension folders?
mv *.gif Images/GIF
mv *.jpeg Images/JPEG
mv *.jpg Images/JPG
mv *.png Images/PNG

# Delete any empty folders related to images folder - delete parent folder last
# Because it will only ever be empty at the end of deleting all other subfolders
if [ "$(ls Images/GIF 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Images/GIF
fi

if [ "$(ls Images/JPEG 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Images/JPEG
fi

if [ "$(ls Images/JPG 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Images/JPG
fi

if [ "$(ls Images/PNG 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Images/PNG
fi

if [ "$(ls Images 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Images
fi

########################################## VIDEOS ##########################################

# Make folders for videos
mkdir Videos
mkdir Videos/AVI
mkdir Videos/FLV
mkdir Videos/MP4
mkdir Videos/MPEG
mkdir Videos/MOV
mkdir Videos/WMV

# Move all videos to folder - Split up files into specific file extension folders?
mv *.avi Videos/AVI
mv *.flv Videos/FLV
mv *.mp4 Videos/MP4
mv *.mpeg Videos/MPEG
mv *.mov Videos/MOV
mv *.wmv Videos/WMV

# Delete any empty folders related to images folder - delete parent folder last
# Because it will only ever be empty at the end of deleting all other subfolders
if [ "$(ls Videos/AVI 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos/AVI
fi

if [ "$(ls Videos/FLV 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos/FLV
fi

if [ "$(ls Videos/MP4 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos/MP4
fi

if [ "$(ls Videos/MPEG 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos/MPEG
fi

if [ "$(ls Videos/MOV 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos/MOV
fi

if [ "$(ls Videos/WMV 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos/WMV
fi

if [ "$(ls Videos 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Videos
fi

########################################## ZIP ##########################################

# Make folder for zip
mkdir Zip

# Move all zip files to folder
mv *.zip Zip

# Delete zip folder
if [ "$(ls Zip 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Zip
fi

########################################## MISCELLANEOUS ##########################################

# Make folder for Miscellaneous
mkdir Miscellaneous

# Delete Miscellaneous folder
if [ "$(ls Miscellaneous 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];
then
    rmdir Miscellaneous
fi

# Move rest of items to Miscellaneous Folder
#mv *.* Miscellaneous
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Do you think that this is right way to test for directory emptiness : `if [ "$(ls Zip 2> /dev/null)" == "" ];` ?

Comment: Make a folder with an item inside that is supported by the script (a .doc file is ok).  Run the script.  Manually find the file that has been moved to a new spot.  Delete it.  Run the script again.  Check to see if empty folders are now deleted or not.

Comment: `mkdir -p Audio/{AIFF,FLAC,MP3,WAVE} || exit 1` will create all folders in a single operation and exit if any failure occurs. (it can also be run if some of the folders already exist without error). Your `==` should be `=`. Use `[ -z "$(ls -A "$dirname")" ]` to test for empty dirs.

Comment: @rkosegi "I don't claim to know a ton about shell scripting and even got the syntax for checking for an empty directory here on SO."

Comment: I created a `.doc` file, ran the script, and it was moved to `Documents/DOC`. I deleted the file from that dir, reran the script, and the directory was removed. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @thatotherguy, not sure why its working differently on two different systems, but this is definitely not how its performing on my system.  I'm on Mac.  I'm really trying to understand the issue and would prefer this not be closed, I don't know why the issue isn't prevalent on other systems.

Comment: Make sure you do not have `ls` `aliased` to anything that would effect its operation. (like e.g. `alias ls='ls -a'` which would show the `dot` files)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes, the original code I collected from SO had 'ls -a' and I changed it to just 'ls' thinking that maybe the hidden files were keeping it from being deleted.

Comment: You could post an example of how it appears on your system. Use `find .` to list the directory recursively before and after each of creating the `.doc` file, running the script, deleting the `.doc` and rerunning the script. Include all output, including the commands you use to run.

Comment: @joe_04_04 you can check with `alias | grep "ls"` to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do away with the conditions protecting `rmdir`, as it will not delete a directory that is not empty.  It will, however, return a non-zero exit code, and generate a message to standard error.

What you could do :

```
rmdir "$directory_that_may_be_empty_or_not" 2>/dev/null || :
```

The `|| :` "eats up" any non-zero return code from `rmdir` (which may or may not matter depending on how you handle or ignore errors).

In other words, let your script attempt to delete all directories, and ignore failure if they are not empty (or, for that matter, if deletion fails due to any other reason, such as access rights).

If this does not fix your problem, then your directories are probably not empty.  They may contain hidden files (beginning with a `.` period), which are not listed by `ls` unless you add the `-a` option.  But do not add `-a` in your code, as it also instructs `ls` to list the `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) special files, and would cause your current code to never attempt deletion.

As an additional note, `||` is a logical operator that allows two statements to be "ORed".  Bash uses lazy evaluation, so the statement to the right is only executed if the one on the left failed (success means return code = 0, failure = any other code).  `:` is a shell builtin that takes no argument, and does nothing except provide a zero return code (like the `true` command).  In this case, it guarantees that the status of the whole construct will be 0.